# Series with fractions in java

Tags: java, fractions

[image: Refer 4th series for better clarification]I need to use loop to find the sum of the following series:

```
(2/3)-(4/5)+(6/7)-(8/9)+......±n
```

I have to use for-loop only for this program. Refer the code to see what I've done:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P64 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the limit");
        double n=sc.nextDouble();
        double sum=0;
        for(double i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            if(i%2==0)
            sum=sum-(++i/i++);
            else
            sum=sum+(++i/i++);
        }
            System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I have tried this out but the output is either 1 or 0.

Comment: The output window doesn't open at all? Are you sure you are correctly executing the application? Please explain in more detail what happens when you start the application, what you see, what errors you get etc.

Comment: it does open to take the input but there is no further process happenning since output is either 0 or 1

Comment: From what I can see, once you take the input, you compute `sum`, and close the application. You might want to `System.out.println` the result of your computation and add `sc.next()` or something similar in the end. This way the program will exit (e.g. the window will close) only when you press a button.

Comment: I did that after reading your first comment and as i said the output is either 0 or 1

Comment: What do you mean by `....+n`? Is it supposed to just add an `n` to the end result, or is was it supposed to read `... (n-1 / n)`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov `...n` means upto `n` or the inpputted number

Comment: @PRANAVAKP, `n` what? N fractions? Or until a fraction is either `(n - 1 / n)` or `(n / n + 1)`?

Comment: 'n' is the final number Example: if `n` is 15, it will come in the denominator, of the fraction. suppose `n` is 14 and even, i will come to the numerator. so that fraction is ignored where 'n' is even.

Comment: This code is unreadable.  No wonder you're having problems.  I would not recommend using the ++ operator that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a separate variable for values as using same in loop and your series will make it complex so, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the limit");
    double n=sc.nextDouble();
    double sum=0;
    double j=1;
    for(double i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
            sum=sum-(++j/++j);
        else
            sum=sum+(++j/++j);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

> ```
> Input: 4
> Output: -0.16507936507936516
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the preincrement/postincrement trickery and made the limit determine the number of terms added up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P64
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the limit");
        double n=sc.nextDouble();
        double sum=0;
        for(double i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            double delta = (2*i)/(2*i+1);
            if(i%2==0)
                sum -= delta;
            else
                sum += delta;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a variable for the alternating `+-` and take a step of two at each iteration:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the limit");
    double n = sc.nextDouble();
    double sum = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    for (double i = 2; i <= n; i = i+2 ) {
        sum = sum + (sign * (i/(i+1)));
        sign = -sign;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simpler is better.

Encapsulating it in a function makes your code easier to test and use outside the main method.

```
/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606895/series-with-fractions-in-java
 */
public class P64 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 10;
        System.out.println(String.format("n: %5d sum: %10.5f", n, series(n)));
    }

    static double series(int n) {
        int sign = 1;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            double x = 2.0*i;
            double term = sign*x/(x+1.0);
            sum += term;
            sign *= -1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```